# Regex pattern to match period and pattern

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a string which I am trying to write an regex for

```
CODAA0870E - This an error string is not valid.
```

I wrote a regex `COD[a-zA-Z0-9]*.....................................`

but the length of the string can vary i.e. after COD till  the period.

The regex needs to check **`COD`** at the start and should end at the `period`**.**`

The code I have written so far does not work

```
 Dim value As String = "daafasfasfCODAA0870E - This an error string is not valid.dfsfsfsfcCODAAvcv0870E - This an second error string is not valid.sdfsdf "
    Dim pattern As String = "COD[^.]+\."
    Dim array() As String = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(value, pattern)
```

Comment: Which language are you using? And what should happen when there are multiple periods?

Comment: I am using vb.net .  Only the first period is relevant.

Comment: Then the accepted answer might not do what you expect as it includes all periods.

Comment: Marvin You are right it did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need this regex:

```
Dim pattern As String = "COD[^.]+\."
```

And to get all matches use:

```
Dim matches As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(value, pattern)
```

[See more code samples here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-matches-vbnet)

Comment: Marvin is right the answer does not work. I tried the pattern but it does not work.

Comment: I have added the vb.net code and I am using the regex.split method it does not work for it.

Comment: No use of `split` method is wrong. You need to use: `Regex.Match` instead.

Comment: It should find the first period and not the last period

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82612/discussion-between-user1339913-and-anubhava).

Answer (score 0):

Think you want something like this,

```
^COD[^.]*\.
```